# Cannot download graphics.py in python

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I cannot get graphics.py when i am running it. I downloaded pip version 21 too but still cannot get it. And I downloaded the zelle code for graphics and even put it in site packages but it just isnt working.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python?

Comment: pip install graphics.py should work then if you only have one

Comment: Hi there, try posting the error message that you see. It might give us a hint of what is happening. But probably @chess_lover_6 is right, give pip a try and update your question with any new error message. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what most people do when starting out with Zelle graphics is simply put `graphics.py` in the same directory as your Python source code that imports it.

Right click on this link [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) to get the library source file.

Import it into your code using:

```
from graphics import *
```

which is usually frowned upon for other packages but is the documented approach for Zelle graphics.  Once this works, you could try to "install" it.  The Zelle graphics source simply advises:

> Put this file somewhere where Python can see it.

If you want to put it in the global site-packages directory, first locate that directory:

```
% python3 -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages())' 
['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
%
```

Then move the library file you downloaded earlier into the site-packages directory you located.

Answer (score 0):

```
from    turtle  import*
reset   ( )
forwart ( 100 )
right   ( 90 )
forwart ( 100 )
right   ( 90 )
forwart ( 100 )
right   ( 90 )
forwart ( 100 )
from    turtle  import*
width   (5)
color   ( 'blue' , 'green' )
begin_fill ( )
for i   in  range   ( 4 ) :
    forwart ( 100 )
    right   ( 90 {)
    end_fill ( )
    >>>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).